# REST web services call can be cached to improve performance

Tags: java, android, rest

As I was going through this list of [interview questions](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/rest-web-services-framework-interview.html#ixzz2xuwkvKYQ) (look at question #2) , I cam across this concept. I am not familiar with this concept.

I looked through some documentation but could not find anything. Can someone explains what this means ? Also.. if possible.. how this can be applied to Android.

Comment: I think, they are talking about the server side (Apache). It will prepare some popular requests on its own instead of to recreate the request every time.
They do not mean, you are able to cache REST WS in your application.
By this method, you can improve responsiveness for your users (your apps)

Answer (score 2):

Well,

Things to keep in mind:

- REST is stateless, so there is no session data stored on the client.
- With a well implemented REST API, the server could be restarted between two
  calls, since every data is passed to the server what is needed to
  serve the request. (scalability, cacheability)
- Web services mostly use POST method to make operations, compared to
  REST that uses GET to access resources.

Some facts:

- Most web server implementations cache GET request by default, but
  they officially do not cache POST methods. (server side caching)
- You can use any cache methods available for HTTP GET:
  http://www.symkat.com/understanding-http-caching (client side caching)

As you can see the key is that REST API uses GET operation over POST. In andorid you can easily implement any of the If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match cache methods. However, the server has to support those methods also.